# Child objects are (seemingly) randomly set to NULL or an 'illegal object'; how to debug that?

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I use Cocos2d-x for a game which I am porting from Cocos2d-iphone. The original programmer seems to have used the 'feature' of Objective-C to not crash on calls to nil objects as a way to do a lot of sloppy things.

If this is related to that I don't know, however, in my code I never call release() manually and certainly not delete or anything like that. I don't even call ->removeObject() at all (although that would not result in the same issue as I have).

Now the problem: when the game is running, at random moments (they won't be random but they seem that way now obviously) child nodes get set to NULL. And this does not only affect my code but als the Cocos2d internals. Example:

```
    CCLog("----------------");
    for(int j = 0; j < this->getChildren()->count(); j++)
    {
        CCObject *child = this->getChildren()->objectAtIndex(j);
        EnemySprite *enemy = dynamic_cast<EnemySprite*>(child);
        if (enemy != NULL) {
            CCLog("Enemy with tag %d found", enemy->getTag());
        }
    }
    EnemySprite *enemy = dynamic_cast<EnemySprite*>(this->getChildByTag(i));
    if (enemy == NULL) {

        CCLog("Now enemy with %d is NULL :(", i);
    }
```

In the getChildren() look, all enemies with the tags are there and print this;

- Enemy with tag 1000 found
- Enemy with tag 1001 found
- Enemy with tag 1002 found

During the game it'll show this a lot, until it shows this;

- Enemy with tag 1000 found
- Enemy with tag 1001 found
- Enemy with tag 1002 found
- Now enemy with 1001 is NULL :(

and crashes.

In my mind, this should be impossible with the above code as I just checked, verified and printed exactly that object...

But even more interesting (maybe only to me, maybe it's some stupid mistake), this

```
 this->getChildByTag(i)
```

randomly goes wrong internally as well; traversing the children, it'll find a NULL and conk out on Cocos2d internal code:

```
        if(pNode && pNode->m_nTag == aTag)
            return pNode;
```

The pNode is then not NULL (that's why the asserts do not trigger) but looks like this:

http://o7.no/137JXC4 (screenshot)

The cocos2d::CCCopying thing is already stuff of nightmares for me in this project; every time I see it I know something is wrong and I have no clue how to find what it is.

I already added a breakpoint at the release() delete line; it's not being called. And I, like I said, am not doing anything like that manually.

I use Xcode / iOS to debug, but the behavior is the same on Android (but on my computer Eclipse is slower that Xcode, especially during debugging).

I understand it would be difficult to give me a solution / cause, however; I would be really happy if someone can tell me how to attack this issue. It happens randomly throughout the (quite large) codebase and I'm at a loss how to find this issue...

I hope someone can help!

Comment: It seems indicative of undefined behavior. One likely cause might be that you store a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Is that significantly different from how that works in Objective C? For instance, if I have a method initEnemy() { EnemySprite *enemy = EnemySprite::create("enemy.png"); this->addChild(enemy, 5, 1000); } Because that's what I do and it's the way the Cocos2dx manual does it.

Comment: Also note that after the loop, `i` will be equal to `getChildren()->count()`, so `i` would be out of bounds in your `getChildByTag` call.

Comment: It prints literally the 'correct' i when the error occurs and I added that code as debugging after all the issues. But you are right it's unclear; I changed it to a j now.

Comment: Have you forgot to retain something that is autorelease?

Comment: Maybe... But I don't think so; is there a way to debug that? In this case the EnemySprite is ->retain(). And yet this happens. I'm looking for some way to debug it because now i'm just wading through the code with the debugger, suddenly something is gone and I don't have a clue where/what happened. Like said, the 'delete xxx' in CCObject->release() is never called; I have both a CCLog and breakpoint there and it's just never called before one of these things happen.

Comment: Also, if that were the problem, the CC system internally would not have issues, because, correct me if i'm wrong, after release the child is no longer in the CCArray which Cocos uses to traverse it's children. While here, the child *is* there but illegal and Cocos itself segfaults when traversing (->visit() or ->getChildByTag() etc).

Comment: Could you post more code? What does the EnemySprite look like? How do you instanciate it? Where does the code you posted come from?

Answer (score 3):

At times dynamic_cast returns 0 even tough its argument was not 0. This happens for example when you're casting a super class to a subclass (so called "down casting"). Check this tutorial for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

I can imagine that if the elements in your list have a generic (unrelated) super type, this can be the problem in your case.

Comment: He, that actually seems like something. I didn't know that. I'm going to check that out, but I feel you might be right. Thank you. Will report back asap.

Answer (score 1):

As you say it's hard to tell, but here are two ideas.

You might try turning on [guard malloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html).

Alternatively, you might gain something from putting a static int counter in your suspect class's (like EnemySprite's) deconstructor/constructor to decrement/increment, and break/log when it falls below zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I'll try guard malloc. However; the destructor is never called; I have breakpoints and ref counters all over the place; EnemySprite is simply not destroyed as far as I can find and yet it's gone...

Answer (score 0):

I only see the definition of `j` what is `i`?
I believe it crashes after `CCLog("Now enemy with %d is NULL :(", i);`
since this line already been logged, it definitely not crashing here.

Comment: i is a counter for (int i=1000;i<1003;i++) in this case. When it reaches that CCLog, enemy is NULL so in that case it indeed doesn't crash. It shouldn't be NULL though there; I don't really understand how it can be NULL in that case.

Comment: @CharlesS : Do you have any node in your code that has a Tag with 1001 other than one of those EnermySprite been added into your `this`? especially some child of EnermySprite?

Answer (score 0):

CCObjects are subject to the AutoReleasePool by default, which means Cocos2D-x will manage when to release the object. If you use the static constructor for these objects, you can call object->retain() and object->release() so that you can manage the memory yourself.

Source: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Reference_Count_and_AutoReleasePool_in_Cocos2d-x

Comment: Yes, I do this and that worked fine in the past. This is an Objective C port from another programmer and something seems off there. I never had this issues before this project using retain/release. Mind you; release is never *called* for the object in this case. That why I say ; 'it just disappears'. I have breakpoints in ->release() and on delete o;...

Answer (score 0):

If something changes the enemy object to NULL, what I would do is setting a data breakpoint at address of enemy(for 1001). Than,

1. If breakpoint is hit, that might be a memory corruption.
2. If breakpoint is not hit and you get NULL, dig into `getChildByTag()`. What I would do then is replacing `this->getChildByTag()` with `dynamic_cast<EnemySprite*>(this->getChildren()->objectAtIndex())` check if the is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

In `Build Settings->Other C Flags->Debug and add -o0` flag and try debugging.